# Is it possible to find the length of the longest word in a text file AND read in the same text file with just 1 while loop?

Tags: c++

I need to find the length of the longest word in a text file, which I will then use for the size of the array I'll make.

I'll then need to store each word from the text file inside that same array (or more precisely, inside a linked list which will be stored inside the array)

Is it possible to do this without reading in the file twice? The file will contain almost 100,000 words and reading the file twice seems extremely inefficient.

Comment: When you say linked list inside an array, do you mean an array of linked lists? Or are you somehow making each element of the array a node in the linked list?

Comment: How do you plan to use this length? Why don't you use `std::string`?

Comment: Please show an [mre] of your closest attempt. You do have a version with more than one loop I assume?

Comment: Are you using dynamic memory allocation or a static array?

Comment: @Roguebantha Yep, an array of linked lists.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov I'm finding the length of the longest word to create an array with that same length

Comment: Please show an example of a small text file and what the resulting array would look like.

Comment: @newbieProgrammer How does the knowledge of the longest word help you? Ok, let's assume you know that size in advance, what's next? So you've created the array, even the array of linked lists... why do you need that?

Comment: Since the word is being stored inside a linked list, why does the size of the array depend on the size of the word? Regardless of how long the word is, the linked list occupies one element of the array, no?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, especially with only 100K words, I'd say that reading the file twice is negligible speed wise, unless you're expecting to do this many many many times a second.

However, I understand reading from disk is expensive. With that in mind, [mmap'ing](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) the file into memory, then performing an [mlock](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mlock) on that memory will guarantee that your reads from that memory area (which will be the file contents, as a memory buffer) do not access disk more than once. In some sense, this is a valid answer your question. According to the kernel, you really are only reading from the file once.

Doing the above requires familiarity with at least a couple system calls that aren't usually necessary when first getting into writing C++. A more "newbie programmer" (forgive the pun) method of doing so might be to get the size of the file using [fstat](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat) or [fseek](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/), allocate a buffer of that size, [fread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/) the entirety of the file into a memory buffer, and then use that memory buffer in accordance with how you might use the mlock'd buffer I described above. That is - treat that memory buffer as the contents of your file, and parse through the buffer and perform whatever operations you need.

If you would like a code example for doing so, I can happily provide as much - however, hopefully this is at least a way of getting started.